# Send notification to a particular User List using Node socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using NodeJS,Scoket.io

I am trying to send notifications like Facebook. If there are 1000 Users and User A have 50 friends then Notification is send to those 50 Users. I do not want to broadcast for all Users

What is the efficient way to do this ?

Comment: Quite a broad question, I suggest you look into http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/ for ways to 'group' socket connections

Comment: you can emit sockets by user session email value or user session username value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is better solution then this but for right now I placed userID in socket object and then loops on userID on which we have to send notifications

Answer (score 1):

If a user has lots of friends then you can have all of those friends listening to a namespace or room for that user.

The explanation and example is here: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Comment: Actually we want something like facebook , for example there is post then 5 another user comments then notification send to those person who comments , Notification system like facebook . Do you work on redis for this purpose ?